# How to change formatting TODO in Org-mode's Latex PDF output

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex, pdf

I want to change font of `TODO`/`DONE` in PDF output of my Org-mode.
Is there any way to change font of `TODO`/`DONE` keywords (also perhaps also change colors)?

[image]

**UPDATE**:
Using `dalanicolai` answer below, I changed my config with following lines:

```elisp
    (defun my-org-latex-format-headline-function
        (todo todo-type priority text tags _info)
      "Default format function for a headline.
    See `org-latex-format-headline-function' for details."
      (concat
       (and todo (format "{\\framebox{\\bfseries\\rfamily\\color{%s} %s}} "
                         (pcase todo-type
                           ('todo "olive")
                           ('done "teal"))
                         todo))
       (and priority (format "\\framebox{\\#%c} " priority))
       text
       (and tags
        (format "\\hfill{}\\textsc{%s}"
            (mapconcat #'org-latex--protect-text tags ":")))))


    (setq org-latex-format-headline-function 'my-org-latex-format-headline-function)
```

[image]

Again thanks `dalanicolai`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A similar question was answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197545/org-mode-latex-export-making-todos-red), but I will write a slightly improved version here, namely one that uses the 'todo-type' argument (as was suggested in the comments of the linked answer). The section 'Advanced Export Configuration' of the org manual (see https://orgmode.org/manual/Advanced-Export-Configuration.html) explains how to add custom filters.

We can start from the `org-latex-format-headline-default-function` and slightly modify it, and use it as the `org-latex-format-headline-function` as follows:

First add the line:

```
#+LATEX_HEADER: \usepackage{xcolor}
```

to the beginning of your org file.

Subsequently, evaluate the following code (e.g. add it to your init file and reload it with `M-x eval-buffer`):

```lisp
(defun my-org-latex-format-headline-function
    (todo todo-type priority text tags _info)
  "Default format function for a headline.
See `org-latex-format-headline-function' for details."
  (concat
   (and todo (format "{\\bfseries\\sffamily\\color{%s} %s} "
                     (pcase todo-type
                       ('todo "orange")
                       ('done "green"))
                     todo))
   (and priority (format "\\framebox{\\#%c} " priority))
   text
   (and tags
    (format "\\hfill{}\\textsc{%s}"
        (mapconcat #'org-latex--protect-text tags ":")))))

(setq org-latex-format-headline-function 'my-org-latex-format-headline-function)
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for I'm slightly changing for my preference. I will update my post with my config shortly.

Comment: Great! Your change looks good!